# What 's equal this :$\lim_{x\to \infty} \operatorname{erf}(\operatorname{erf}(\operatorname{erf}(\cdots \operatorname{erf}((x)))))) $?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, function-and-relation-composition, error-function

Error function is a special function (non-elementary ) ,it is defined as follow :$$\operatorname{erf}(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-x}^x e^{-t^2}\ dt,$$ I would like to know what's  equal this limit : $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \operatorname{erf}(\operatorname{erf}(\operatorname{erf}(\cdots \operatorname{erf}((x)))))). $$

**Note:** I know only this :$\lim_{x \to \infty} \operatorname{erf}(x)=1$  and $\operatorname{erf}(\operatorname{erf}(\operatorname{erf}(\cdots \operatorname{erf}((x)))))) $ is a composition of $\operatorname{erf}$ $n$-times.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3):

One may use $\lim_{x \to \infty} \operatorname{erf}(x)=1$ and one may use the fact that $\operatorname{erf} (\cdot)$ is *continuous* over $\mathbb{R}$, then
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \operatorname{erf} (\operatorname{erf} (\operatorname{erf} (\cdots \operatorname{erf} (x)\cdots)=\operatorname{erf} (\operatorname{erf} (\operatorname{erf} (\cdots \operatorname{erf} (1)\cdots)
$$ where $\operatorname{erf}$ appears $n$ times on the left hand side and $n-1$ times on the right hand side.

Comment: u just did substitution , i meant in my question if it has a fixed value for x go to infty

Comment: If $n=2$ then computing this limit amounts to computing $\text{erf}(1)$, which is already hard, so I'm not sure what kind of answer you're hoping for.

Comment: it must to show some clarification for my question

Comment: Maybe I don't get the question. As it stands, if $n$ is *fixed* then the number on the right hand side is also a *fixed* real number as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @user51189 Since $erf$ is continuous $\lim_{x \to \infty} erf(erf(x)) = erf\left( \lim_{x\to \infty} erf(x) \right) = erf(1)$.

Comment: Are you looking for a closed form?

Comment: yes , exactly this what i meant , in my guess i think it's limit will be 1

Comment: sorry just a wrong typo , i mean erf(1)

Comment: Since we have $\operatorname{erf} (\operatorname{erf} (\operatorname{erf} (\cdots \operatorname{erf} (1)\cdots)\neq \operatorname{erf}(1)$, I don't see how the limit can be equal to $\operatorname{erf}(1)$.

Comment: just a guess and that the reason let me asking the question , now how do i get it's limit without investigating for it's closed form as u cited in ur comment above